# C++ - an exception-safe way to assure a global cleanup function gets called

Tags: c++

Context:

Suppose an external library requires that its `globalCleanup()` function gets called in order to assure all its resources are cleaned up (it might allocate some global resources during any of its calls.) A client function `client()` does this before each of its many `return`s but of course this is not exception-safe and the code is repetitive.

Problem:

Is there an elegant way to assure this global function gets called on the `client()` exit? Defining a dummy class whose only purpose is to call a global function in the destructor (RAII style) is an option, but maybe there's something simpler?

TLDR: How to call a global cleanup function RAII-style?

Comment: Read about [ScopeGuard](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Scope_Guard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Cleaner {
  public:
    Cleaner() {}
    ~Cleaner() { ExtLib::CleanGlobal(); }
};

void client() {
  Cleaner cleaner;

  // Code that works with ExtLib
}
```

Comment: Yup, my first thought. It could also take a `void (*f)(void)` in the constructor and call it in the destructor to be a little more reusable. I'll accept if nothing better pops up. Btw, there should be a class like this in Boost :)

Comment: @Rafal Dowgird: There is infact a `boost::scope_exit` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include "loki/ScopeGuard.h"
client()
{
    LOKI_ON_BLOCK_EXIT(globalCleanup);
    // some codes here
}   // globalCleanup will be called when exit this block
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it a class that cleans up in the destructor seems like the best choice to me. (Assuming the library isn't implemented as classes already.)